# How do I use a PHP Buildpack after creation?

Tags: php, heroku, buildpack

Let me start of with saying I'm very new to Heroku.

I've been looking through their documentation and other people's, and I can't seem to find the "starting point" unless I am to recreate the app. I can do that, if necessary, but would rather not.

I want to customize their standard PHP Buildpack:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

I need to add in a few more extensions (mbstring, gettext, etc.)

Seeing how it builds everytime you push it to the master, it seems there should be a fairly easy way to build it.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

You need to fork a copy of their build pack:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/

Then add a config variable to read from your builadpack

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/[username]/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```